# How to get Microsoft.Research.Kinect reference to work for Kinect SDK 1.6 in VS 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, kinect

I am working on a project on VS 2012 C# and I get build mistakes because of the Microsoft.Research.Kinect reference which is not included in the instalation of the Kinect SDK 1.6. I have already copied the Microsoft.Research.Kinect folder from the Kinect Beta 1 SDK for the project to work with the Kinect SDK 1.6 and it still doesn't work. How can I get the Microsoft.Research.Kinect reference avaliable for my project?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the "References" folder in your project in VS2012 and browse to the assemblies you want to reference.  In your code, be sure to include them:

```
using Microsoft.Research.Kinect;
```